# How to redirect "relationships/received" to "user/[requestee:uid]/relationships/received?

Tags: rules, users

(D7) When a user sends a friend's invitation to another user (User Relationships) the other user, once he logs in, sees a green message that informs him so-and-so sent him a friends request. There is a link that takes the viewer (requestee) to *example.com/relationships/received.*

However, I have created a view that displays the received requests in a different format. Of course the page view has a different path and I want the user to be redirected to: *user/[uid of the requestee]/relationships/received* and the requestee only to be allowed to see the requests he received.

I have created a rule (Rules module) as follows:

- Event: A user relationship has been requested
- Condition: Relationship has type *(friend)*
- Action: Page redirect *(user/[requestee:uid]/relationships/received)*

*[requestee:uid]* is in the allowed replacement patterns but it doesn't work. Clicking on the link still takes the viewer to the original path.

What do I do wrong? 
:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to redirect to the current user profile page, you could try using the redirect module with [redirect_token](https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect_token)

```
Use tokens in "To" paths in Redirect module.
```

Then you can redirect from http://example.com/relationships/received to http://example.com/user/[user:uid]/relationships/received

Comment: [user:uid] and [requestee:uid] don't work as tokens with redirect_token. However, [current-user:uid] does work and it's fine for my purpose. Thanks. :)